# How to output added text fields into PHP using FOREACH command

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, foreach

This is my script I use to dynamically add/remove input text fields. I'm using the container properties so I can make multiple individual blocks for this input field.

```
$(function(){
    $('.container > a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this= $(this),
            prnt = $this.parent(),
            i = prnt.find('input').length;
        if($this.hasClass('add')){
            $('<div><input type="text" class="field" name="dynamic[]" value="' + i + '" /></div>').hide().fadeIn('slow').appendTo($('.inputs',prnt));
        }else if($this.hasClass('remove') && i > 1){
            prnt.find('input.field:last').remove();
        }else if($this.hasClass('reset') && i > 1){
            prnt.find('input.field:gt(0)').remove();
        }
    });
})
```

This is the html code I am using to build the input field:

```
<div class="container">
<a href="#" class="add">Add</a> | <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a> | <a href="#" class="reset">reset</a>
    <div class="inputs">
        <input type="text" name="dynamic1" class="field"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need a PHP code to output all the fields from the input fields. If I add 3 input fields, I want the PHP code to output all of those input fields one after another.

I tried using the foreach code:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['dynamic[]'] as $value) {
echo "$value <br />"; // change this to what you want to do with the data
}
?>
```

But I keep getting errors on the 2nd line (the foreach line)

How do I do this? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

```
foreach($_POST['dynamic[]'] as $value) {
```

To

```
foreach($_POST['dynamic'] as $value) {
```

Thats is if you have HTML like this

```
<input type="text" name="dynamic[]" class="field"/>
<input type="text" name="dynamic[]" class="field"/>
```

But with your current HTML `<input type="text" name="dynamic1" class="field"/>` you can see that `$_POST['dynamic']` is not a array you should just echo it like this

```
echo $_POST['dynamic1'] ;
```

Comment: This works for the 2nd field, but it can't catch the data for the very first(initial) field! How do I get the data for the first field to show up as well? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

instead of `$_POST['dynamic[]'` try `$_POST['dynamic']`

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['dynamic'] as $value) {
echo "$value <br />"; // change this to what you want to do with the data
}
?>
```